# PHP - How can I store data in an array to split it afterwards without getting in trouble?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo

Ok. Here is the scenario.
I'm getting data(of a statusmessage) of my database table and storing every result in my array. Every result contains multiple rows. 
It contains

```
statusID, posterID, statusMessage, dateTime, sumRating, sumVotes
```

So when I got multiple status messages in my table I want to print them all on the site. 
Logically I know just do this

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($results); $i++)
        {
            echo $results[i];
        }
```

And now I get all data of all type. 
But now, when I want to play a little with the data and format it or, let's say, I don't want the data to be printed out one after one. I want the posterID, then I want a little PHP code or CSS or whatever.

So, what I'm doing now, is, that I currently save my data like this

```
foreach($statusMessageResult as $row){
            $results[] = $row['statusID'] . "," . $db->getUsername($db->getUserNameById($row['posterID'])) . "," . $row['statusMessage'] . "," . $row['dateTime'] . "," . $row['sumRating'] . "," . $row['sumVotes'];   
        }
```

So now, in my for-loop, I just split the current entry of the result-array at every comma.

```
$statusMessage = $results[$i];
            $statusMessageSplit = explode(",", $statusMessage);
            echo "This status is written by: " . $statusMessageSplit[1] . " and has the ID: " . $statusMessageSplit[0] . "<br>";
```

What my problem is, that, when a user writes a

```
,
```

in his status Message it will be split again. So, what can I do to solve this better?

Comment: Change the delimiter from ',' to '|'?

Comment: Uhm... just an idea: an *array of arrays*...!?

Comment: @Jordan Because surely nobody will ever write anything with an "|" in it.

Comment: @deceze Precisely ;) Your solution is better ;)

Comment: Do what deceze says! It does not make sense to create a string array just so you can split up the string to a new array. Create a multidimensional array and then do the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this using two-dimensional/jagged arrays:

```
foreach($statusMessageResult as $row)
    $results[$row['statusID']] = array($db->getUsername($db->getUserNameById($row['posterID'])), $row['statusMessage'], $row['dateTime'], $row['sumRating'], $row['sumVotes']);

//usage:
foreach($results as $index => $rowArr)
    echo "StatusID: $index:\r\n" . var_export($rowArr);
```